# How to passing object as parameter in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, object, types, arguments

If we have the following simple code in C#:

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          string x = "Hello World";
          test(x);
          int y = 101;
          test(y);
          Console.ReadKey();
      }

      static void test(object val)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(val);
      }
}
```

So, we have a **reference type object** as parameter - works fine. How to do a similar thing in C++?

OT: Without direct typing we can use **var** keyword, in C++ exists keyword **auto**. Is here any similar reference type like object or some way/tricks to prove it?

Comment: So you're basically interested in how to pass objects by reference?

Comment: @H2CO3 It doesn't appear so, and in any case the C# code isn't passing the object by reference; it's passing it by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, not all objects derive from a common base type; there is no universal run-time polymorphism. You might get the behavior you need, however, by using compile-time polymorphism via templates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T> void test(const T& val)
{
    std::cout << val << "\n";
}


int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    std::string x = "Hello World";
    test(x);
    int y = 101;
    test(y);
}
```

Comment: You should define `basic_ostream& operator<< (Yourtype& val )`, if `Yourtype` is not a standard type.

Comment: True, for some reason the fact about overloading the operator fell out of my mind.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have a "root type" similar to C#'s `System.Object`. You can use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/any.html) to emulate the concept, but that requires using an external library.

As far as passing parameters by reference, you could pass by reference in C++ by using `MyType &myTypeRef` syntax, or pass by pointer `MyType *myTypePtr`.

Comment: The parameter isn't being passed by reference in the C# code, fyi, it's simply passing a reference type by value.

Comment: @Servy Yes, that's the usual way the parameters of reference types are passed around in C#.

Comment: I'm not saying the C# code is in any way wrong, or that passing the parameter by reference in C++ would be wrong, merely that they are *different*, and have different semantics.  The "direct port" would be passing a pointer by value, rather than a value by reference.  The OP may not care, but I felt it was worth mentioning the difference for the C++ buffs without much C# experience.

Answer (score 0):

as C++ does not enforce a common base type for all types you can't do exactly the same thing. However, you can use templates to achieve the same thing:

```
 void fn(....)
 {
      string x = "Hello World";
      test(x);
      int y = 101;
      test(y);
  }

  template <typename T>
  void test(const T& val)
  {
      cout << val;
  }
```

Comment: This won't compile because `test` is being called before it has been defined.

Comment: Of course it won't, even more because argument list of fn is (....). It is obviously an example, not something to be pasted into production code